# Android receiving too much Bluetooth debug data

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I use Bluetooth low energy to connect with a heart rate sensor.

Now I get so much logcat data in Eclipse from Bluetooth, I see nothing more.
654 lines per second.
The phone on which I run the code is a HTC one.
Maybe someone knows where it is going wrong?

Here a Example.

```
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.003: E/bt-btm(3108): No PF filter has been configured!
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): HAL bt_gatt_callbacks->client->adv_filter_cb
09-12 16:16:40.003: E/bt-btm(3108): No PF filter has been configured!
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: D/BtGatt.GattService(3108): onAdvFilterConfig() - action=2 status=1
09-12 16:16:40.003: E/bt-btm(3108): No PF filter has been configured!
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.003: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
09-12 16:16:40.013: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.013: D/BtGatt.GattService(3108): onAdvFilterConfig() - action=2 status=1
09-12 16:16:40.013: E/bt-btm(3108): No PF filter has been configured!
09-12 16:16:40.013: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_dm_sm_execute event:0x2a
09-12 16:16:40.013: I/bt-btif(3108): bta_brcm_evt_hdlr :0x0007
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing, but it only happens on a phone, not on the Nexus 7.

Comment: I have observed this or something similar when the app crashes while or shortly after performing a search for a BLE unit and attempt connection. It seems to continue until you reboot the phone :-/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is hapening on bluetooth.
But a suggest you to filter logcat messages.
By opening filter configurations, on left side of logcat messages, you can add of edit filter configurations. Click on `+` or edit your current configuration.
It will open a screen like the image below.
To filter only your application logs you must put your package id on **by Application Name:**
The most important to you happens on **by Log Tag:** filter. You could put a deny regex to exclude especific tags, it would be like that: `^(?!bt-btif)`.
[image: filter configuration]

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ignoring the messages might not be a good idea, I suspect these messages to the source of the power drain I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, these logs are printed by a native library to help the developers debug the app, unless you have issues with the Bluetooth module, it should not cause trouble.

Basically `PF Filter` is just a packet filter which means, all packets are accepted from the client instead of having rules to block some.

Logged from btm_ble_adv_filter.c in external/bluetooth/bluedroid/stack/btm/

```
   if (NULL == p_bda_filter ||
    /* not a generic filter */
    (p_target != NULL && p_bda_filter))
{
    BTM_TRACE_ERROR("Error: Can not clear filter, No PF filter has been configured!");
    return st;
}
```